# lm318n as noninverting amplifier

Tags: amplifier, audio, microphone

I am trying to amplify an audio signal generated by a hydrophone. I am trying to work from this (very general) circuit diagram I have found online and in an electronics textbook I own.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvDtcw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

However, I am confused about what input and outputs correspond to what. The hydrophone is attach to a coaxial cable, which is diagrammed as such on its data sheet. [image]

As of now I am using a connecter to break out the coaxial cable to a "positive", and "negative" wire. So, currently, my circuit is as such, with ground representing the 0v terminal on the bench top power supply I am using.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7ITzh.png)</sup>

When I measure my Vout with an oscilloscope with the power supply turned on, I get a randomly oscillating garbage output, so clearly I am doing something wrong. Are all of my input and outputs correct. Should I be completing the circuit by connect Vout to gnd, or the + terminal of my hydrophone?

Comment: (1) Your power supply needs to be split-rail. Vs+ - 0 - Vs- with 0 as the circuit ground. Is this what you've got? (2) 100 Ω is too low for most op-amps as it may draw more current than the op-amp can supply. 10 kΩ would be more reasonable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LM318 is quite a lively amplifier.

As a minimum, you need to make the following changes

a) Bypass the power supplies close to the package with small value capacitors
b) Raise the feedback resistor values, 100ohms is too low
c) Provide a DC bias path to your amplifier input
d) Decouple the transducer input

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffM5Zw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

While the data sheet says this amplifier will be stable at unity gain, so more stable at the gain of two here, all that will be for naught if you've built a bird's nest on a proto-board.

A good way to get oscillatory performance out of an otherwise good amplifier is to drive a pure capacitive load with it, like a coaxial cable into an oscilloscope. Decouple the output with a few 10s of ohms series resistor (R4) so the amplifier isn't driving the capacitance directly.

The data sheet does talk about stability modifications you can make with extra capacitors connected to pins not shown on this simple schematic. If you are still having problems, read these parts carefully.

Excess capacitance to ground at the amplifier -ve input, through perhaps a bird's nest board, or bad PCB layout, can also destabilise an amplifier. A few 10s of pF placed across R1 (C4) can sometimes restore stability in these cases.

If R3 is too low a value for your transducer, check the amplifier data sheet to see how high a value you can use. It is possible to bootstrap this resistor to reduce the loading if needed. Although unlikely to be necessary at this low gain, a capacitor in series with R2 reduces the DC gain of the amplifier to unity, to allow a large input offset voltage due to a large R3 value to be tolerated.

Comment: you've labelled C4 and R4 as see text F and Omega, respectively. What were you referring to by this. Otherwise thank a ton.

Comment: See my answer. Generally when a component in a schematic is labelled 'see text', it means you have to refer to the text that talks about the schematic. As a hint, read through my answer and see whether you can spot any words (text) that refer to those components.

Comment: Also, to clarify, do the ground symbols on your diagram correapond to the 0v terminal of the power supply? Thanks for your patience. Im a relative beginner.

Comment: As far as DC continuity is concerned, yes. However, it would be unwise to wire it like that. I tend to pick a single point in the amplifier (star ground point), and wire the critical ground connections back to that. These connections are the input and output socket grounds, the feedback network ground (R2), the power supply decoupling caps (C2, C3) grounds, and the wire from the power supply. Less critical (R3) might as well ground there anyway. Sometimes I use a die-cast box as the 'star point', not quite a point but very low resistance and small size, grounds the connectors, and all else